# Google Analytics include querystring

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, referrer, query-string

I've taken an advert out on a site with instruction to point it to:

http://www.example.com/?source=gmb

In Analytics, how do I go about analysing it's data?  I can't find anywhere to see people who came via that querystri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"source" is not a valid campaign tracking variable.

Use [Google's URL Builder](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55578).

Comment: Thanks!  So if I use that, it will track it in Analytics?  These ads are being served privately (not Adwords).

Comment: Yes - the URL builder is used to create campaign-specific tracking links (AdWords should automatically create these links for you if your Analytics and AdWords accounts are linked - for all other campaigns, use the URL builder)